# StringCases: return list of outputs for each of several patterns

Tags: string-manipulation

According to the documentation,

```
StringCases[{s1, s2, ...}, p]
```

returns

```
{StringCases[s1, p], StringCases[s2, p], ...}
```

but, oddly enough,

```
StringCases["string", {p1, p2, ...}]
```

returns the results which match *any* of the patterns $p_i$, which is essentially equivalent to

```
Union[{StringCases["string", p1], StringCases["string", p2], ...}]
```

Is there a way to modify `StringCases["string", {p1, p2, ...}]` to return just

```
{StringCases["string", p1], StringCases["string", p2], ...}
```

in an analogous manner to how `StringCases[{s1, s2, ...}, p]` does it?

One alternate way to get the same output would be

```
Through[Table[StringCases[#, p[i]] &, {i, n}]["string"]]
```

but I was curious if there was another way.

Comment: `StringCases["string", #] & /@ {p1, p2}`

Comment: @Kuba: Looks good, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
p = {"abc", "cd"};
string = "abcdabcdcd";

StringCases @@@ Thread[{string, p}]
(* {{"abc", "abc"}, {"cd", "cd", "cd"}} *)
```

---

Original post:

```
StringCases[string, p, Overlaps -> All]
(*  {"abc", "cd", "abc", "cd", "cd"} *)
```